# Charts with Highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to create dynamic charts with Highcharts.
I'm using the example provided by the Highcharts Web Site but it doesn't work.

The code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<script src="highcharts/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="highcharts/js/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="highcharts/js/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Additional files for the Highslide popup effect -->
<script src="highcharts/highslide-full.min.js"></script>
<script src="highcharts/highslide.config.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    // Get the CSV and create the chart
    $.get("data/regperop_tmp_2.php", function (csv) {
        console.log(csv);
        $('#container').highcharts({

            data: {
                csv: csv,
                dateFormat: 'YYYY-mm-dd'
                },
            title: {text: 'TITLE'},
            subtitle: {text: 'Subtitle'},

            xAxis: {
                tickInterval: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one week
                tickWidth: 0,
                gridLineWidth: 1,
                labels: {
                    align: 'left',
                    x: 3,
                    y: -3
                }
            },

            yAxis: [{ // left y axis
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                labels: {
                    align: 'left',
                    x: 3,
                    y: 16,
                    format: '{value:.,0f}'
                },
                showFirstLabel: false
            }, { // right y axis
                linkedTo: 0,
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                opposite: true,
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                labels: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -3,
                    y: 16,
                    format: '{value:.,0f}'
                },
                showFirstLabel: false
            }],

            legend: {
                align: 'left',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 20,
                floating: true,
                borderWidth: 0
            },

            tooltip: {
                shared: true,
                crosshairs: true
            },

            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            click: function (e) {
                                hs.htmlExpand(null, {
                                    pageOrigin: {
                                        x: e.pageX || e.clientX,
                                        y: e.pageY || e.clientY
                                    },
                                    headingText: this.series.name,
                                    maincontentText: Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) + ':<br/> ' +
                                        this.y + ' visits',
                                    width: 200
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    marker: {
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                }
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'All visits',
                lineWidth: 4,
                marker: {
                    radius: 4
                }
            }, {
                name: 'New registration'
            }]
        });
    });

});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container" align="center" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSV data are provided by a PHP script.
I put the console.log(csv) in order to verify the format of the data and the result is:

```
Data, OP1, OP2, OP3, OP4 
 2016-10-19, 6645, 10381, 0, 4069 
 2016-10-20, 6222, 10097, 0, 3905 
 2016-10-21, 6440, 10076, 0, 3784 
 2016-10-22, 6696, 10495, 0, 3860 
 2016-10-23, 6820, 10464, 1, 3890
```

I can't understand why the code is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery should be loaded before Highcharts library.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script> 
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/ocmm5581/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces in your CSV (Assuming that you copied/pasted the CSV as it is) :

```
Data,OP1,OP2,OP3,OP4 
2016-10-19,6645,10381,0,4069 
2016-10-20,6222,10097,0,3905 
2016-10-21,6440,10076,0,3784 
2016-10-22,6696,10495,0,3860 
2016-10-23,6820,10464,1,3890
```

According to RFC 4180:

> Spaces are considered part of a field and should not be ignored.

Comment: I deleted spaces but nothing changes